# Symfony 2.3 add form collections of entities

Tags: forms, symfony, collections

I'm triying to make a dynamic form adding collections inside an entity.

I have followed the code example in the [Symfony's documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#basic-usage), and it works, but what I want to do is add a new form (the form of the entity collections).

So, if I have an entity `A` that contains a collection of entities `B`, I want to add new entities `B` dynamically in the form, but I don't know how to do it.

The entity A form should be something like:

```
$builder->add('entityB', 'collection', array(
    'type'   => 'HOW TO PUT THE FORM OF THE ENTITY B???',
    'options'  => array(
        'required'  => false,
    ),
    'allow_add'=>true,
));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the [Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html):

```
$builder->add('entityB', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new EntityBType(),
    'options'  => array(
        'required'  => false
    ),
    'allow_add' => true
));
```

This is assuming that you have created a Form Type Class for `EntityB` (not manually creating it when needed in your controller). The linked cookbook entry gives a lot of good examples based on per-case situations.

Comment: Thanks!! you put an extra ')' after EntityBType hahaha
I was looking the example in the Cookbook but I can't get it to work. I copied the code, but the link to add doesn't appear :(

Comment: Finally I get it using the jQuery code explained in the documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#basic-usage)